# Translate data of xml file

Tags: xml, translate

I want to translate the data of an xml file to another languages. Which is the easiest way? I found a simple program but does not translate well. Is there any good way or any way to transform it in other formats and after translate? 
I use notepad++ to access my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "Other Languages". Generally for Transforming XML to something else, you would use XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations).

Comment: i have the English version and i want to translate it to other European languages. How can i use the Xslt and from where?

Comment: The short answer is "You can't". The slightly longer answer is "You can, but it's ridiculously complicated". (Basically parsing all natural language data values, and throwing Google Translate at them, then you'l need some sort of way to translate currencies, dates. decimals and other locale specific information. The XML file itself must also contain some sort of locale identifier.

In short, you are trying to use XML for something you aren't supposed to. Try using JSON instead, at least that way your values would be typed.